# MySQL Union and Average

Tags: mysql, database, sum, union, average

I've no idea if I am using **UNION** correctly in this scenario - there may well be a better/easier way and I'm open to suggestions:

I have the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG (q1) AS q1, AVG (q2) AS q2, AVG (q3) AS q3, AVG (q4) AS q4, AVG (q5) AS q5, AVG (q6) AS q6, AVG (q7) AS q7, AVG (q8) AS q8, AVG (q9) AS q9, AVG (q10) AS q10, AVG (q11) AS q11, AVG (q12) AS q12, AVG (q13) AS q13, AVG (q14) AS q14, AVG (q15) AS q15, AVG (q16) AS q16, AVG (q17) AS q17, AVG (q18) AS q18, AVG (q19) AS q19, AVG (q20) AS q20, AVG (q21) AS q21, AVG (q22) AS q22 FROM thotels_results WHERE brand = 'EFG' AND date = 'NOV2010' GROUP BY brand
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG (q1) AS q1, AVG (q2) AS q2, AVG (q3) AS q3, AVG (q4) AS q4, AVG (q5) AS q5, AVG (q6) AS q6, AVG (q7) AS q7, AVG (q8) AS q8, AVG (q9) AS q9, AVG (q10) AS q10, AVG (q11) AS q11, AVG (q12) AS q12, AVG (q13) AS q13, AVG (q14) AS q14, AVG (q15) AS q15, AVG (q16) AS q16, AVG (q17) AS q17, AVG (q18) AS q18, AVG (q19) AS q19, AVG (q20) AS q20, AVG (q21) AS q21, AVG (q22) AS q22 FROM thotels_results WHERE brand = 'XYC' AND date = 'NOV2010' GROUP BY brand
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG (q1) AS q1, AVG (q2) AS q2, AVG (q3) AS q3, AVG (q4) AS q4, AVG (q5) AS q5, AVG (q6) AS q6, AVG (q7) AS q7, AVG (q8) AS q8, AVG (q9) AS q9, AVG (q10) AS q10, AVG (q11) AS q11, AVG (q12) AS q12, AVG (q13) AS q13, AVG (q14) AS q14, AVG (q15) AS q15, AVG (q16) AS q16, AVG (q17) AS q17, AVG (q18) AS q18, AVG (q19) AS q19, AVG (q20) AS q20, AVG (q21) AS q21, AVG (q22) AS q22 FROM thotels_results WHERE brand = 'ABC' AND date = 'NOV2010' GROUP BY brand
```

It outputs the following:

```
       q1      q2      q3   etc.                                                                                        
140 8.7714  8.8429  8.1643  8.7500  8.7571  8.9000  9.4071  9.1214  8.5714  8.7643  9.5143  8.9429  9.1643  8.9857  7.9500  8.9286  8.7000  9.0429  9.0143  8.7214  9.1214  9.3071
29   8.1724  8.2414  8.2414  7.8966  8.5862  8.5517  9.0000  8.5862  8.1724  7.9655  8.8966  8.6207  8.2414  8.3793  7.8276  8.3793  7.9310  8.4138  8.6897  8.3448  8.8621  8.5172
897 8.6009  8.5686  7.8528  8.3133  8.3423  8.6410  9.0301  8.6912  8.3233  8.3389  9.2029  8.3969  8.6856  8.5017  7.8071  8.4816  8.3512  8.6789  8.6789  8.3913  8.6388  8.8986
```

All I would 'like to do' is **AVERAGE** each of the q1, q2, q3 columns or **SUM** them and divide by 3.

Like I say, if there is a better way that doesn't use JOIN, that's fine with me!!!

Thanks in advance,

Homer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) You don't need to calculate the results separately and then `UNION` them like that. (2) I think [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) will probably do what you need.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), AVG (q1) AS q1,... 
FROM thotels_results WHERE brand in ('ABC','EFG','XYZ') AND date = 'NOV2010'
GROUP BY brand
WITH ROLLUP
```

But as pointed out in the comments this doesn't do the "mean-of-mean"s averaging required. The best I could come up with for that is

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results 
SELECT 
       brand, 
       COUNT(*) AS cnt, 
       AVG (q1) AS q1
       ...
FROM thotels_results 
WHERE brand in ('ABC','EFG','XYZ') AND date = 'NOV2010'
GROUP BY brand;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE results2 
SELECT cast(NULL as char), AVG(cnt), AVG(q1) 
FROM results r2;


/*MySQL doesn't allow the same temp table to be accessed twice in a UNION!*/
SELECT * FROM results r
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM results2;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE results;
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE results2;
```

Comment: I was going to recommend pivoting over brand, but a rollup is much nicer for the maintainer. +1

Comment: Small problem - the averages aren't correct - so for example q1 ROLLUP is showing as 8.6116.  If you add the three on Q1 together and divide by three you get 8.5149 - any thoughts?  I really really like this approach - very clean and crisp!!!

Comment: Hmmm, The averages probably are correct but in a different way. Do you actually need a mean of the mean that weighs all 3 products equally regardless of the number of records in each brand? That will give brand `XYC` which only has a count of `29` a disproportionate weight when compared to brand `ABC` and its count of `897`

Comment: Yep, it's a strange one - I don't need them weighted (at least not at the moment!) - for consistency I'm looking to SUM the three scores and divide by 3  the 8.5149.(the current 8.6116 may well be the weighted mean, not sure haven't calculated it yet!) - Thanks Martin.

Answer (score 1):

Without a JOIN, why not just use a temp table or table variable. So insert the SUMs:

INSERT INTO tempTable (SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(q1) AS q1.... FROM thotels_results WHERE brand = 'EFG' AND date = 'NOV2010' GROUP BY brand)

INSERT INTO tempTable (SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(q1) AS q1.... FROM thotels_results WHERE brand = 'XYC' AND date = 'NOV2010' GROUP BY brand)

INSERT INTO tempTable (SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(q1) AS q1.... FROM thotels_results WHERE brand = 'ABC' AND date = 'NOV2010' GROUP BY brand)

Then fetch the adverage

SELECT SUM(q1) / 3 as q1Adverage,.... From tempTable